# DFP targeting doesn't work: "Cannot find targeting attribute"

Tags: google-dfp

I've got a website set up with DFP (small business), and I'm trying to differentiate ads by project id.

I went into the DFP back-end, and set up (in Inventory - Key-values) a targeting key "projectid" Type Free-form. In the site I added a line of code to send the projectid as a targeting value (in angular)

```
DoubleClick.setTargeting('projectid', data.id);
```

I set up a test ad for project id 27, but the right ad is not appearing. Using the DFP Console I see the following:

```
Information 1 ms    Created service: publisher_ads
Warning 1 ms    Cannot find targeting attribute "projectid" for service "publisher_ads"
Information 1 ms    Created slot: /12345678/NTR_300x600-290px-ad
Information 2 ms    Associated service "publisher_ads" with slot "/12345678/NTR_300x600-290px-ad".
... and lots more
```

Why is it not finding the targeting attribute? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

A little late, but as much as i know the values on kvps NEED to be sent as strings.